# How to decompose the data of date in R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

in R, I got the data class of date as follow:

```
20100701
20100702
20100703
20100704
```

how could I transform them to the follow form:

```
2010 07 01
2010 07 02
2010 07 03
```

the data of year,month and day in 3 columns.

Comment: It's unclear how to answer your question. Could you please edit to include the output of `dput(myinputdatahere)` so that we can replicate what you're working with? That'll provide us with the metadata necessary to answer your question exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to mention, this can also be done (although maybe less conveniently than with package `lubridate`) with functions `strptime` and `format.POSIXct` from the `base` package :

```
x <- c(20100701,20100702,20100703,20100704)
strptime(x, format="%Y%m%d") -> y
data.frame(year=format(y,format="%Y"),month=format(y,format="%m"),day=format(y,format="%d"))
  year month day
1 2010    07  01
2 2010    07  02
3 2010    07  03
4 2010    07  04
```

Answer (score 4):

This is very straight-forward if you use the package `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- ymd(dates)
data.frame(y=year(x), m=month(x), d=day(x))
     y m d
1 2010 7 1
2 2010 7 2
3 2010 7 3
4 2010 7 4
```

---

`lubridate` provides a stack of convenience functions to work with dates.  In this example:

- `ymd()` converts a string to date, guessing what the format is.
- `year()` extractst the year
- `month()` extracts the month
- `day()` extracts the day

Answer (score 1):

Some dummy data:

```
dates <- c("20100701", "20100701", "20100701", "20100701")
```

To get dates:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(dates)
Using date format %Y%m%d.
[1] "2010-07-01 UTC" "2010-07-01 UTC" "2010-07-01 UTC" "2010-07-01 UTC"
```

To get a dataframe, and just split the string:

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(year=str_sub(dates, 1, 4), month=str_sub(dates, 5, 6), day=str_sub(dates, 7, 8))
  year month day
1 2010    07  01
2 2010    07  01
3 2010    07  01
4 2010    07  01
```

Comment: You could easily get rid of the stringr dependency by changing `str_sub` to `substr`